# jQuery include file - functions assigned to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, include

I have a .JS include file, that applies to several pages.  However, for one page I have now adopted a jquery method, and to use

```
$("").on("click","#id",function(){});
```

on some of my elements.  But now when I goto a page that doesnt have that element on it, It flags up as an error.  Is there anyway around this so that It just simply ignores these elements if they dont appear on the page? Otherwise I would have to write seperate .JS files for each page and I'm sure that's not the correct way to do this.

Thanks for your help. :)

(note: i am specifying tags etc i was just giving an example, i apolagise, i removed the tag name.  Lets call the tag #mydiv.  When using the above clause, on a page that doesnt have #mydiv, then i get a console error.  It is perfectly fine on the pages that DO have #mydiv, however! So the question is: how can i stop that error from being caught?)

Comment: jQuery, assuming it's loaded on **all** of your pages, is very good at handling the case when zero elements match a selector. That said, I don't think `$('')` is a valid selector. If you don't have a more specific element to use, go with `$(document).on(...);`.

Comment: `$("")` is guaranteed to select nothing. And what is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error should be related with something else since `on` won't throw any error if some element doesn't exist. Try with

```
$("body").on("click","#id",function(){});
```

If could also use an inner container instead of `body`

```
$("#your-control-container").on("click","#id",function(){});
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it was because i was using $(document).on("click".... It is sorted now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark, and guess that the pages that don't need the jQuery part don't load jQuery using a `<script>` tag prior to including the `.js` file mentioned. If that is the case, your jQuery code will throw an error because the `$()` function (which is just a shorthand for `jQuery()`) isn't defined.

You should be able to get around that by testing that `window.jQuery` isn't undefined in your JavaScript file:

```
if(window.jQuery) {
    // code that uses jQuery here
}
```